# Zend Framework internal routing

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting

For example, I have a page in my application called page2 that I want to access like mysite.com/page2

in the application.ini file I would have a section for it

```
resources.router.routes.index.route = '/page2/'
resources.router.routes.index.defaults.controller = index
resources.router.routes.index.defaults.action = page2
```

My question is, what if I have several pages that I want to access as children of the index controller. There must be a method that doesn't involve creating a new section in application.ini every time I have a new page...

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [StaticRoute plugin](https://github.com/jara/jara-base/blob/master/library/Jara/Plugin/StaticRoutes.php) by Ekerete Akpan uses reflection to inspect your default controller and add static routes of the form `/actionname` for all action methods it finds there.

This means that you don't have to add an explicit route for each of those actions. Just add an action to the default controller and the corresponding view-script in the expected place. No need to change any routing files or `application.ini` just to add a new top-level url.

Note, however, that since the plugin uses Reflection to inspect your default controller, using it has performance implications.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for... and yes, programming is all about give and take! :) thanks again